# Why Accelerate vDSP_vsaddD doen't work as described in documentation?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to add scalar value to a vector but this isn't working as expected:

```
import Accelerate

let array = [1.0, 2.0]
var result = [Double](repeating: 0, count: array.count)

var add = 3.0
vDSP_vsaddD(array, 1, &add, &result, 1, vDSP_Length(array.count))
print(result) // [0.0, 0.0]
```

I'm getting [0, 0] instead of [4, 5]. The same thing happens with vDSP_vsmulD.

Comment: I'm using XCode Playground for testing my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was the XCode/Playground fault. I ran the same code on physical iPhone and it worked as I expected.